# Why "a b c [2] d c" -match "b c [2]" is False?

Tags: powershell, match

Below predicate returns False which I expected True

```
"a b c [2] d c" -match "b c [2]"
False
```

But

```
"a b c d c" -match "b c"
True
```

This returns True. I wonder what is the reason.

Comment: Remember to escape `[`! `-match "b c \[2]"`

Comment: the `[]` chars are reserved regex pattern modifiers. if you want to match them, you MUST escape them. take a look at what you get from using the `regex]::Escape()` method on your match pattern. [*grin*]

Comment: Thank you @MathiasR.Jessen below returned True. 

`"a b c [2] d c" -match "b c \[2\]"
True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, regex escape.  You don't need to backslash the spaces.  Brackets are used for regex character ranges.

```
[regex]::escape("b c [2]")

b\ c\ \[2]


"a b c [2] d c" -match [regex]::escape("b c [2]")

True


"a b c" -match "[a-c] [a-c] [a-c]"

True


"a b c " | select-string "([a-c] ){3}"  # the whole match is highlighted in ps7

a b c
```

Answer (score 2):

The [ is a regex character and must be escaped.

```
PS> "a b c [2] d c" -match "b c \[2]"
True
```

Edit: Mathias beat me to it while was typing.